# Apache2 Reverse Proxy only showing default page

Tags: apache, apache2, proxy, node-js, reverse-proxy

I'm completely new to Apache. I have a Django backend that serves as an API and a SvelteKit frontend. Django runs on `0.0.0.0:8000` and SvelteKit on `0.0.0.0:3000`.

I'm trying to setup Apache so it uses SvelteKit on port 3000 when users access the Website via port 80.

I followed some guide online but by now I worked through way too many, so I can't find it anymore... I'm using Debian and I created a directory called "example" in `/var/www/` next to the default "html" directory. I also created a `example.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. My config looks like this:

```
<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
    Options None
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://0.0.0.0:3000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://0.0.0.0:3000"

    ServerAdmin my@email.example
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost api.example.com:80>
    ProxyPass "/api" "http://0.0.0.0:8000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://0.0.0.0:8000"

    ServerName api.example.com
    ServerAlias www.api.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I'm having is that both, the frontend and the API backend, are not showing up in the browser when I type in my domain. `www.api.example.com/api` doesn't find anything and `www.example.com` only returns the default Apache page. It works when adding ":3000" at the end of `www.example.com` but I want it to be on the standard HTTP port.

Another strange occurrence is that when I enter "apache2ctl -S" it returns an IP address as a VirtualHost that leads to a website saying that I've "successfully started the Nginx proxy manager". Not sure if I'm getting things right here but I haven't even installed Nginx on my server as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```xml
<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
    Options None
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000"

    ServerAdmin my@email.example
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass "/api" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://127.0.0.1:8000"

    ServerName api.example.com
    ServerAlias www.api.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The `VirtualHost` tag specifies which network interfaces it listens on.  "example.com" is a domain name not a network interface, so configuration for it doesn't belong there.  Aparche uses the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` configuration to determine if the virtual host is relevant for any given request.

You should also use `127.0.0.1` rather than `0.0.0.0` to refer to another services running on the same server on a different port.  `0.0.0.0` won't route and shouldn't work.

I also removed the `DocumentRoot`.  Since the entire virtual host is reverse proxied, you shouldn't need to map it to a directory on disk.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation @Stephen Ostermiller ! I applied your changes and it's not showing the Apache default page anymore. However it just gives me a blank page now with a lot of proxy errors in the console. Do you perhaps know why that is?

Edit: I fixed it by adding another / to the end of my proxy paths. In case anyone runs into the same issue